# Passing Array to method

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have simple code Scenario:

```
class Demo
{ 
  static void check(int z[])
 {
   z=null;
 } 

}

class arrNullCheck
{
  public static void main(String args[])
 {
    int arr[]={2,3,4,5};

    Demo.check(arr);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
       System.out.print(arr[i]);

      }     
  }
}
```

According to me this program should throw null pointer exception at runtime as z is equal to null,But output is as follows:

```
Output: 2 3 4 5
```

If i update method like:

```
 static void check(int z[])
 {
   z[0]=9;
 }
```

then it will update array with value 9 as expected. why doesn't null work here then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't throw an exception. Java is a *pass by value* language, and references are also passed by value. You cannot reseat references either. The `z` is a *copy* of a reference to `arr`, and when you reassign to `null` in your method, you are only changing the value of the *local copy* and not of the original `arr`.

Comment: Then what about 'z[0]' element in updated method, it should not update 'arr' too.

Comment: Yes it will. `z` points to the same thing that `arr` points to. When you do `z[0] = 9`, you're not modifying `z` at all. You're modifying the value at location `0` in the array that `z` points to.